# How come iwconfig bitrate output is proved wrong by current download rate?

Tags: wifi

When I run

```
iwconfig
```

I get

```
Bit Rate:1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
```

and more. Running a download at the same time, Firefox reports a download rate of 1.8Mbit/s. What does iwconfig report? Is it some kind of nominal rate?

Comment: Not sure which bitrate that is, esp. as there can be different transmit and receive bitrates. Use `iw wlan0 station dump` to get both bitrates. Also note the bitrate can change on demand/due to current noise environment.